# Prove that this function is differentiable at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix} \sin x, & x \in \Bbb Q\\
0, & x \in \Bbb R\backslash \Bbb Q\end{matrix}\right.$$

1. Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$
2. Find $f'(0)$

What I did was $f'(0)= \lim_{x\to0} \dfrac{\sin x-\sin0}{x-0} = \lim_{x\to0} \dfrac{\sin x}{x}$

And I don't know how to go from there, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ is not differentiable at $0$ !

First note that $f(0)= \sin 0=0,$ since $0$ is rational.

Now let $(r_n)$ be a sequence in $ \mathbb Q \setminus \{0\}$ such that $r_n \to 0.$ Then

$$ \frac{f(r_n)-f(0)}{r_n -0}= \frac{ \sin r_n}{r_n } \to 1,$$

as $n \to \infty.$

$If (s_n)$ is a sequence in $ \mathbb Q^c$ such that $s_n \to 0.$ Then

$$ \frac{f(s_n)-f(0)}{s_n -0}= 0 \to 0,$$

as $n \to \infty.$

Comment: It is even not continuous at $0!$. SCNR

Comment: this is so weird because, I didn't type the question wrong, this is how my professor gave me the question.. so I thought i am probably wrong and tried to solve it. he should've worded it "prove or disprove". thank you so much again Fred.

Answer (score 0):

f is not differentiable at x=0. The limit u calculated is 1 and is true only for rationals. This limit is 0 for irrationals. Therefore, there is no limit for  limx->0 f(x)/x and this is why f is not differentiable at x=0.